# Can I force WinAPI / ATL to convert CRLF to LF when opening a file?

Tags: c++, winapi, atl

I'm not very familiar with how `fopen` in the standard C library works under the hood but it seems to preserve '\r\n' line endings in "b" mode and convert them to '\n' in the "r" mode. I would like to achieve the same effect using WinAPI or ATL, would that be possible?

Comment: The Windows API doesn't allow you to specify a file mode. It will always read and write raw binary data. But why don't you use the [I/O streams](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) library?

Comment: I want to use memory-mapped files in my .obj loader project without using any library that isn't OS-specific or part of C++'s STL.

Comment: A memory-mapped file maps the binary data 1:1 into memory. There is no customization point where you can implement transformation of that data. You'll have to implement that on a higher level of abstraction.

Comment: Yeah, I just thought that since `ATL::CAtlFileMappingBase` requires a valid `HANDLE` obtained from `ATL::CAtlFile` there would be such abstraction already in place (ATL does abstract away some WinAPI mechanics after all). Guess I'll just have to remember to convert my files to LF beforehand.

Comment: ATL abstracts away *resource management*. It doesn't invent much logic on top of that (with the exception of some COM helpers). The `HANDLE` (in this case) represents a file, usually acquired from calling [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew). This is unrelated to ATL. It's unclear why you even need any CR/LF translation to begin with. You are operating on binary data after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the API level functions simply give you the data as stored. Just like the C run-time functions can provide Unicode data in a variety of UTF encodings and the API functions can not.